# Cowboy: How do you present a static html file from a handler?

Tags: erlang, static-files, cowboy

I am using cowboy and I have a post method to a handler which checks for user name and password. This all works great.

Many of the examples show how to return a simple hello message in response. Unfortunately, I would like to serve up a html file in response to the correct details but I cannot see how to do this from a handler?

I know how to serve static files using the cowboy static file handler but I do not know how to serve a static file from my own handler.

Comment: Hi, further reading of the Nine Nines website indicates you can add a sendfile tuple. https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.5/guide/resp/ the tuple has to include the file length. Anyone know how to efficiently calculate a file length using erlang? Thanks

Comment: The following code worked but I had to enter the file length manually.

Req = cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>}, {sendfile, 0, 2591, "/home/cowboy/examples/eventsource/priv/Device.html"}, Req0),

Two issues with this solution are: 1) You have to manually set the file length. Not sure how to do this in Erlang. 2) You have to give the full path to the file. Would like to use the priv_dir.

MPC

Answer (score 0):

Finally a solution which uses priv_dir and solves the filesize issue:

```erlang
FileSize=filelib:file_size(code:priv_dir(eventsource)++"/CP.html"),

Req = cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>}, 
      {sendfile, 0, FileSize, code:priv_dir(eventsource) ++ "/CP.html"}, Req0),
```